# Queries fired on Partition Table are slower

Tags: sql-server, partition

I have one scenario where i had to partition the table based on Account ID which is a nvarchar column with duplicate values.

Example- we have 1000 AccountID data from AC0001 to AC1000.
I have created 10 partitions AC0100,AC0200...AC1000.

once i had implemented partitioning , queries are slower than previous and scan count is equal to no of partitions i created i.e. partition elimination is not happening instead scanning through all partitions

am i correct to create partition on string datatype ?
Please provide your response

Comment: Seems that you wanted an index instead of a partition.

Comment: EzLo. Unpartitioned table is working fine but the Partition table which i created is working slower than unpartition table even though both tables are having clustered index on AccountID and fired the same query to both the tables. Unpartitioned table is giving ScanCount=1 and Partitioned table is giving ScanCount=11.

Comment: A. You provide too little information for choosing partitioning strategy. Does it make sense at all? How many records you have in your table? What are parameters of your storage subsystem? Do you have a lot of unexploited IO? 
B. I suppose that https://dba.stackexchange.com/ is suited better for this question

Comment: @user1469712 Why did you suppose that partitioning will make your table faster in the first place? 
As for varchar datatype - it depends on length, if your AccountIDs have reasonable length - it absolutely normal

Comment: Ingaz Thanks for your responce.  We have OLTP system where we are loading data for today in the mean time users will be viewing reports so reports are getting blocked until data insertion is not completed due to exclusive locked. To avoid those blocking we are trying to implement partitioning where new data load will happen on different partition and users will be extracting reports in different partition. We have total data of 125 million.

Comment: When the partition elimination is not happening, are you providing the exact AccountID value in the query? If it's a variable, are the datatypes exactly the same?